# Why does dispatch submit a wrong payload?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, axios, submit

I want to pass the data of my form via the dispatch function to my action function and send a request from there with axios. But in the action function something completely different is logged in the console, getters, commit, ...

Thanks for your help.

**Action payload:** [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNf8A.png)

**Store action:**

```
const actions = {
  async sendReport(payload) {
    console.log(payload)
    await axios
      .post("http://xxxxxxxxxx:8081/api/admin/bugreports/", payload)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },
};
```

**View function:**

```
 function report() {
      store.dispatch("company_report/sendReport", {
        text: state.report,
        user: state.user_info.id,
      });
    }
```

*The payload in my view logged the correct values as payload.*

**Form:**

```
<form @submit.prevent="report()">
      <input v-model="state.report" name="report" id="report" class="input" />
      <button type="submit" class="second-btn btn">Absenden</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first argument is not payload in action it is a context that exposes the same set of methods/properties on the store instance the second one is your payload

```
const actions = {
  async sendReport(context,payload) {
    console.log(payload)
    await axios
      .post("http://xxxxxxxxxx:8081/api/admin/bugreports/", payload)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },
};
```

you can read more about vuex action from [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is my first project in vue.